# Finding markers within a SQL Server database from a google maps startingpoint with a radius

Tags: sql-server, geolocation, neighbours

I'm new to geodata and I am playing around with google maps, asp.net and SQL Server, but I'm a bit stuck.

I got a SQL Server table with markers with there longitude and latitude.

And I want to get the 10 nearest markers from the database relative to a startingpoint.

What is the best way to do this.

The server is a SQL 2005 and the values are stored in two columns datatype nvarchar(300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use C# or ASP.NET for this reason, just use SQL request. Here is example from [AdventureDataworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) sample database for finding neighboring locations:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2
GO
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(-121.626 47.8315)';
SELECT TOP(7) SpatialLocation.ToString(), City FROM Person.Address
WHERE SpatialLocation.STDistance(@g) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SpatialLocation.STDistance(@g);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but i'm using an sql server 2005 and the longitude and latitude are two columns nvarchar(300) Its an existing database so can't convert it.

Comment: @user1016456 - that's quite pertinent information (2005, values stored as nvarchar) that you ought to edit into your question, since 2008 has spatial data types, so most people would guess that that's what you're working with.